# Why doesn't the NFS client work in Windows 10 PRO?

Tags: nfs, windows-10

Apparently the nfs client feature is available for windows 10 PRO but not working according to this [thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c1b1d99f-ba29-41f7-af4c-e5ec2e5f8b69/client-for-nfs-is-not-licensed-for-use-on-this-version-of-windows-error-windows-10-1439310?forum=WindowsInsiderPreview)
Any way to make it work?

Comment: Perfect. I've unlocked the question. You can now post an answer. Thanks!

Comment: okey now I understand better you way of thinking. thanks. I will then slightly change the answer to make some sense in the context. @E

Comment: Sounds good. Also, it's not "my way of thinking". Rather, it's how things work on this site and on Stack Overflow, and all other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Yeah but I mean your way of thinking in the context of the community style of course, not yours personally. Please add comments if I need to change things in my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

### NFS's client from windows have finally been updated for Windows 10 PRO.

So with your latest `windows 10 PRO 14393.576`, your NFS's client is finally operational in comparison with before like shown in this [thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c1b1d99f-ba29-41f7-af4c-e5ec2e5f8b69/client-for-nfs-is-not-licensed-for-use-on-this-version-of-windows-error-windows-10-1439310?forum=WindowsInsiderPreview): as stated before by Tom jolly Tom Jolly (Group Software Engineering Manager) in the same thread, they were working on a fix because of problems with the transition from Windows Ultimate and Windows Enterprise 7 to Windows 10 PRO. It has been released in the last update.

Don't forget to install the nfs client from Windows features (will show some images later). To mount the share you can do it through Explorer like you would do with samba share so

```
\\x.x.x.x\share
```

or you can do it through command line with mount

```
x.x.x.x:/share or \\x.x.x.x\share drive:
```

**Some things you should know.**

- User permission won't really work out of the box like to would be in
  Linux. So it is very probable that Explorer accept to map the share
  but won't accept to enter the share. So begin to set up a share where
  everybody will be able to write and read. So with chmod -R 777. I guess that the nfs client is not totally implemented.
- Software like `acronis true` won't be able to enter the share either
  because it seems that a whole extended interfaces features have been
  added to Explorer so guess is that software have to be coded to
  implement those  yet.
- Don't be afraid of the big latency that Explorer seems to have in
  comparison of Linux, again the implementation is not yet perfect.
- if you map through command line to a drive letter, the mapping won't survive      a reboot.

  *If anyone else have some new knowledge based on experience or reading about others bugs and possible problems with this NFS's client, please do share*.